# How to combine my PHP registration system with Joomla registration?

Tags: php, session, authentication, joomla, registration

I have a custom PHP system.

I'm trying to make a calendar with RSVP and other functions, but I notice that Joomla has advanced plugins. My question is how can I send data from my custom registration form to Joomla DB.

And also how can my users access Joomla protected pages (sessions) when using my custom login form?

It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

All of this is possible.

It sounds like you want to take an existing login form and turn it into a custom Joomla login module. Here is a link to Joomla's documentation on how to create a custom module.

http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_create_a_custom_module%3F

Here is another about modifying the Joomla Login module.

http://docs.joomla.org/Customising_the_Login_Form_module

There is no quick way for me to teach you how to do this but I would start by learning the Joomla Module structure and tearing apart (a backup of) the existing Joomla mod_login (login module) so you can understand how it works.

Then its just a task of mashing your custom PHP login page into it.

Not cut and dry but definitely possible.

A quick Google search yielded many results with people trying to modify customize the Joomla login process. I recommend you join the Joomla boards and start reading as much as you can about it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for joomla 1.6-2.5 (and prob 3.0 but not tested). dont think this works on Joomla 1.5

So in your model file make a function that has something like:
This uses the minimum amount of fields (Name,email,username,password) ... and i use the email as username

```
<?php
//create or link joomla user
JModel::addIncludePath(JPATH_BASE.'/components/com_users/models');
$params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_users');

$forMYSQL = array();
$forMYSQL['id']     = '';
$forMYSQL['name']       = JRequest::getVar('fname').JRequest::getVar('name');
$forMYSQL['username']   = JRequest::getVar('email');
$forMYSQL['email']      = JRequest::getVar('email');
$forMYSQL['groups'][0]  = 2;    //Registered user group, 
//$forMYSQL['groups'][1]    = 8;    //Super Admin user group
$forMYSQL['password']   = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword(); //Random password.
$forMYSQL['password2']  = $forMYSQL['password'];

//If a email is found....
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `#__users` WHERE `email`='%s'", $forMYSQL['email']);
$this->_db->setQuery($query);
$checkuser = $this->_db->loadObject();
if ($checkuser->id > 0) {
    //E-mail in use already NOT CREATING....
} else {
    //EMAIL NOT USED... CREATING Joomla user
    $userModel =& $this->getInstance('User', 'UsersModel');
    $userModel->save($forMYSQL);

    $newuid = $userModel->getState('user.id');
    if ($newuid > 0) {
        //User created.


    } else {
        //ERROR USER NOT CREATED.
    }
}
?>
```

So that works if your inside of joomla.. idealy inside of a model file of a component... Otherwise you can load up the joomla framework and then run that code by loading this next code sniplet:

```
// START: Initialize Joomla framework
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));    //This needs to point to the root of your joomla
// Including Required Files
require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
// Create the Application
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('administrator');
$mainframe->initialise();
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
//Including Required Joomla libarys
jimport('joomla.application.component.model');
jimport('joomla.application.component.modelitem');
jimport('joomla.application.component.modellist');
// END: Initialize Joomla framework
```